# R newbie asking about loops

Tags: r

I am trying to subset a portion of dataframe by a grid value,
then save to a new dataframe.
It is already working for me, but since I have 13 dataframes, my current code is rather clumsy and looks like this.

```
    b1<-subset(a1, a1$Gene.Symbol %in% 'YAP1') 
    b2<-subset(a2, a2$Gene.Symbol %in% 'YAP1') 
    b3<-subset(a3, a3$Gene.Symbol %in% 'YAP1') 
    b4<-subset(a4, a4$Gene.Symbol %in% 'YAP1') 
    b5<-subset(a5, a5$Gene.Symbol %in% 'YAP1') 

    b13<-subset(a13, a13$Gene.Symbol %in% 'YAP1')
```

My problem is already solved (brute force) but for the sake of improving, can anyone help with a loop for the above command?

I tried:

```
    for (i in 1:15) {
    b[i]<-subset(a[i], a[i]$Gene.Symbol %in% 'YAP1')
}
    for (i in 1:15) {
     bi<-subset(ai, ai$Gene.Symbol %in% 'YAP1')
}
```

neither worked, sadly.

Comment: The R way to do this following most good practice advice would be to have those a1 to a5 objects stored in a list, then use lappy on this list to apply the same transformation on all items.  Additionally `subset(a1, a1$Gene.Symbol %in% 'YAP1') ` can be written `subset(a1, Gene.Symbol %in% 'YAP1')`. even better if a1 to a5 can be in a single table if they have the same columns

Comment: It is best to create a list of your data frames, then use lapply to loop over the list.

Comment: For these types of questions I find the Rstudio Community to be a great place to find answers, eg https://community.rstudio.com/t/using-subset-in-for-loop/129801/2

Comment: Please share example data with dput(), so everybody can re-run your code example.

Comment: The issue is all these sequentially named objects. Either put them in a single data frame, or put them in a `list`. See my answer at [How to make a list of data frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames) for more example and discussion.

Answer (score 2):

The code that you tried is already a huge improvement over the code above—just a three-liner where everything can be easily inspected.

The reason why it doesn't work is that you have 13 different data.frames. Accessing them is difficult, but not impossible.

```
a1 = "foo"
a2 = "bar"

get_ai = function(i){ get(paste0("a", i)) }
as = lapply(1:2, get_ai)
as # list with "foo" and "bar"
```

This way you will be able to get a list of all your data.frames and then work on them as you have tried before.

```
bs = list()
for(i in 1:2){
  bs[[i]] = paste(as[[i]], "baz")
  }
bs # list with "foo baz" and "bar baz"
```

Notice the `lapply` that we used before? It's quite similar to `for` cycle, just abstracted away. We could do the same with `bs`, and we don't even have to define `bs = list()`, since it will be allocated automatically! This makes `lapply` a tad bit more efficient than `for` cycle. We just need to call it with a function.

```
cs = lapply(as, function(x){ paste(x, "baz") }) # a lot of brackets
identical(bs, cs)
```

Looks like you want to learn and improve, great! So I won't write a solution to your problem here: you should be able to figure it out from these examples.

My advice is (as mentioned in comments), try to load the data.frames `a1`, `a2` etc. in a `list`, or even just manually put them in a list before you start doing operations on them.

```
as = list(
  "a1" = a1,
  "a2" = a2,
  "a3" = a3
  )
```

and so on. Explicit is better than implicit, and trying to obtain loaded objects from your environment (the `get` call) is not very explicit.

Comment: I think you should add an answer, to benefit future users and improve this Q+A for general use. Then the OP can decide whether to look at it or not.

Comment: @JayBee I included a generic solution, I just didn't include a specific solution. Future users will want a generic solution, not a specific one.

If you have specific suggestions, feel free to suggest changes.

Comment: Interesting, I always thought solutions should be complete/specific, but seems there are various views. Meta discussion here if of interest: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/428083/should-answers-be-general-or-specific

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data looks something like this, and you absolutely want to use a `for` loop and assign the output to new variables in the global environment, you can do this:

```
set.seed(1)
a1 <- data.frame(x=sample(6), Gene.Symbol=paste0("YAP", rep(1:2, 3)))
a2 <- data.frame(x=sample(6), Gene.Symbol=paste0("YAP", rep(1:2, 3)))
a3 <- data.frame(x=sample(6), Gene.Symbol=paste0("YAP", rep(1:2, 3)))

objnames <- grep("^a\\d+$", ls(), value=TRUE)

for (i in objnames) {
    assign(gsub("a", "b", i), subset(get(i), Gene.Symbol == "YAP1"))
}

b1
#   x Gene.Symbol
# 1 2        YAP1
# 3 3        YAP1
# 5 1        YAP1
b2
#   x Gene.Symbol
# 1 6        YAP1
# 3 3        YAP1
# 5 5        YAP1
b3
#   x Gene.Symbol
# 1 5        YAP1
# 3 4        YAP1
# 5 3        YAP1
```

But as other people have mentioned, the more ***R*** way to do it, would be to put your data in a list, and then loop over it using `lapply()` or one of its relatives. Lists in R are a bit like small environments that you can work within and loop over very conveniently. In fact, you can convert back and forth between environments and lists, so if you really want to "export" the elements of a list, and make them available in the global environment, you can do this quite easily, but it's rarely desired.

```
ll <- mget(objnames)
ll.sub <- lapply(ll, subset, Gene.Symbol == "YAP1")
ll.sub
# $a1
#   x Gene.Symbol
# 1 2        YAP1
# 3 3        YAP1
# 5 1        YAP1
# 
# $a2
#   x Gene.Symbol
# 1 6        YAP1
# 3 3        YAP1
# 5 5        YAP1
# 
# $a3
#   x Gene.Symbol
# 1 5        YAP1
# 3 4        YAP1
# 5 3        YAP1
# 
names(ll.sub) <- gsub("a", "b", names(ll.sub))
ll.sub
# $b1
#   x Gene.Symbol
# 1 2        YAP1
# 3 3        YAP1
# 5 1        YAP1
# 
# $b2
#   x Gene.Symbol
# 1 6        YAP1
# 3 3        YAP1
# 5 5        YAP1
# 
# $b3
#   x Gene.Symbol
# 1 5        YAP1
# 3 4        YAP1
# 5 3        YAP1
# 

list2env(ll.sub, .GlobalEnv)
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
b1
#   x Gene.Symbol
# 1 2        YAP1
# 3 3        YAP1
# 5 1        YAP1
b2
#   x Gene.Symbol
# 1 6        YAP1
# 3 3        YAP1
# 5 5        YAP1
b3
#   x Gene.Symbol
# 1 5        YAP1
# 3 4        YAP1
# 5 3        YAP1
```